# How to translate a Javascript message in an html page

Tags: javascript

On my html page I have a block of Javascript code like this:

```
    title() {
      if (this.type === "varA") {
        return "message 1"
      } else if (this.type === "varB") {
        return "message 2"
      } else if (this.type === "varC") {
        return "message 3"
      } else if (this.type === "varD") {
        return "message 4"
      } else if (this.type === "varE") {
        return "message 5"
      }

    },
```

How can I translate the messages included in the return ?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what exactly do you mean by translate ?

Comment: Please read the "*[ask]*" guidance, because we have no idea what you're doing, what you're expecting, how or why your attempts are failing, or even what code you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to translate 'message1, message2' messages translate to the selected language.

you can simply use this :

```
// dict object
var LOCALE = {
en : {
  "HELLO": "Hello", 
},
fr : {
"HELLO": "Bonjour", 
},
tr :  {
'HELLO' : 'Merhaba'
}
};

// choose language
var lang = 'en';

String.prototype.translate = function () { 
    return LOCALE[lang] ? LOCALE[lang][this] : this;
};

alert("HELLO".translate())
```

or you can use [jQuery Localisation](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html)